# Submit a form in Dart using an HTML link

Tags: html, dart

Let's say I have a form:

```html
<form id = "form1" action = "process.php" method = "post">
...
</form>
```

Now, submitting it from JavaScript using link would look like this:

```html
<a href='javascript:document.forms["form1"].submit()'>Submit</a>
```

How do I do the same with Dart-lang?

Comment: You shoudn't use link as submit button for any form. You have to use the <input type="submit" value="Submit"> to allow the enter key to work. See my post below for the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can use inline dart script inside `href` attribute of `<a>`.

However, you can add a onClick handler on your anchor :

```dart
import 'dart:html';

main() {
  AnchorElement a = query("#a1");
  a.on.click.add((e){
    FormElement form = query("#form1");
    form.submit();

    // stop event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
}
```

And your anchor can look like :

```html
<a id="a1">Submit</a>
```

If you need to retain the hand cursor (because it's now gone after taking the useless `href`) or style it otherwise, just use CSS:

```css
a {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #00f;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alexandre Ardhuin gived you a good head start, but you have to use a `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` to allow the user the use the enter key on their mobile device or on their keyboard:

```
<form>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And dart code:

```
main() {
  Element form = query("form");
  form.on.submit.add((e){
    // Do your stuff here...

    // Stop event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  });
}
```